# How to conditionally match location in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'd like to set up nginx location match but only for a specific source address. Unfortunately if I already match a location, but not the condition I can't fall through to the next location. What's the way to solve it nicely?

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        index app.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }
    ...
    location ~ ^/admin {
        if ($source_trusted = "UNKNOWN") {
            return 403;
        }
    }
    ...
    location ~ ^/... {
        fcgi_pass ...
        ...
    }
}
```

With this config going to `/admin` from a source that sets `$source_trusted = OK` (via geo module) results in a `404`, rather than the page loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that nginx generally only evaluates one `location` unless specifically instructed to use another, such as when calling to a named location in `try_files` (which you do).

So when you hit the `^/admin` location, you only need to do whatever is appropriate. In this case, it's most likely going to be exactly the same `try_files` as you used in `location /`.

```
    location ~ ^/admin {
        if ($source_trusted = "UNKNOWN") {
            return 403;
        }
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }
```